# Oracle correlated subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have table that contains fields:

```
USER_ID
MANAGER_USER_ID
COST_CENTER
```

I need to query all of this data, but `COST_CENTER` should be from manager, so I have made this:

```
select USER_ID, COST_CENTER, MANAGER_USER_ID
from EMDB e
where COST_CENTER in (
    select COST_CENTER
    from EMDB e2
    where e2.USER_ID = e.MANAGER_USER_ID
    );
```

Sample data:

```
USER_ID    MANAGER_USER_ID    COST_CENTER
user1      user3              employeeCostCenter1
user2      user3              employeeCostCenter1
user3      manager3           employeeCostCenter2  <-- this is manager

Sample output:
USER_ID    MANAGER_USER_ID    COST_CENTER
user1      user3              employeeCostCenter2  
user1      user3              employeeCostCenter2  
user3      manager3           costCenterOfManager3
```

But this doesn't work (returns nothing).
Any suggestions?

Comment: share sample data and its output

Comment: so all three will come in output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select e.USER_ID,
       e.MANAGER_USER_ID
       e2.COST_CENTER             
    from EMDB e
      inner join EMDB e2 on e2.USER_ID = e.MANAGER_USER_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
SELECT e.user_id, e.manager_user_id, e2.cost_center
FROM emdb e
INNER JOIN emdb e2
ON e2.user_id = e.manager_user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to put the subquery in the select clause:

```
select 
  user_id, 
  manager_user_id,
  (select cost_center from emdb m where m.user_id = e.manager_user_id) as cost_center
from emdb e
order by user_id;
```